# Understanding the difference between the arguments units and input_dim for Dense layer

Tags: keras

Assuming I have a dataset of size (1000, 64) where 64 is the number of columns (i.e., features). In Keras, suppose I want to build a NN model as the following architecture:

1. **Input layer:** Obviously should be one layer having a number of neurons equal to the number of features in my dataset. Hence, the number of neurons here = 64.
2. **Hidden Layer:** I want to this hidden layer to have 100 neurons.
3. **Output Layer:** This is one neuron because I am working with a binary classification problem.

Now, to build the aformentioned architecture in Keras, I usually do the following:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=64, input_dim=64, activation='tanh'))  # Input layer
model.add(Dense(units=100, activation='tanh'))  # Hidden layer
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')) # Output layer
```

The problem is that I cannot distinguish between the arguments `units` and `input_dim` for the `Dense()` layer (For the role as the first layer (Input Layer)). I do understand that `input_dim` is meant to specify the number of features in your dataset (which is in my case = 64), but I don't understand the role of `units` here **for the input layer**. Should `units` be 64? In another word, is the argument `units` supposed to be the same `input_dim` for the input layer?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let looks at the pictorial representation first

[image]

In terms of keras sequential model notations, you will need two Dense layers (marked as dotted boxes in the figure)

1. Dense Layer 1: It should have 100 neurons and each neuron takes as input 64 features so the definition for this dense layer will be
   `Dense(units=100, input_dim=64)`
2. Dense Layer 2: You want one neuron here and it takes the output of the previous dense layer as the input. `input_dim` is not required for the dense layer because it is connected to the previous dense layer in the sequential model and whatever the previous dense layer outputs, it takes in as input (for each neuron)
   `Dense(units=1)`

So the model will be :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=100, input_dim=64, activation='tanh'))  # First Hidden layer
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')) # Output layer
```

You can think of `Dense(units=m, input_dim=n)` as a layer having `m` neurons, with each neuron having `n` inputs. This layer will output `m` outputs (one from each neuron).

Comment: Got it. Gentle and clear explanation. Thank you very much.

Comment: In case of two hidden layers (exclusing the output layer), would the second hidden layer be `model.add(Dense(units=64,activation='tanh'))` ?

Comment: @EthanC, yes correct just keep on adding dense layers with `units` as the number of neurons. In the last layer, it will be `1` neuron with `softmax` for mulitclass or `sigmoid` for binary class

Comment: A bit extreme case, if I want the second hidden layer to be 200 neurons (again, excluding the output layer) in theory it is possible, isn't it?, would the second hidden layer be `model.add(Dense(units=200,activation='tanh'))`?

Comment: @EthanC. yes , theoretically there is nothing wrong about have a huge number of neurons in a layer and also the code snippet for 200 nuerons is correct. However, whether increasing the breadth will increase the model accuracy is something you have to check using cross-validation.